# ReceiverCallNotAllowedException crash from Google Play Services on Android Wear

Tags: wear-os

I'm seeing occasional crashes from my apps on the watch that give the following stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mypackagename, PID: 3487
android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
 at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:179)
 at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:168)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.s.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.j.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Although the crash is reported from my app, you can see from the tracs that none of the code is mine - it's all GMS and platform code.

In other words, I understand the nature of the error, but it's not in my power to fix it. My app does use `BroadcastReceiver`s, but I don't register any `Intent` handlers in them.

A solution to this would be great, but I'm also posting it here in the hopes that someone from the Wear platform team might see it. Wear platform bugs I've posted to the Android issue tracker get closed with a status of "wrong forum" (such as  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=95740).